# Adding a formula as custom function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm effectively trying to hide a monstrously long formula behind the scenes so we can just use something along the lines of =function(cell) rather than the seven-and-a-half line formula I've written.

I can't find the right formatting to add the formula to the new function.

I feel like I need to have a way to reference the cell but I don't know how to tell vba that what *was* A2 could be anything, if that makes sense

```vb
Public Function MiddleName()

Application.WorksheetFunction(LEFT(TRIM(LEFT(MID(A2,FIND("","",A2)+2,FIND(""and"",A2,FIND("","",A2)+2)-LEN.....
```

(formula goes on a while)

[image]

I am hoping that I can use the formula to avoid having to change the cell references in the current formula, as there are over 30. I get error messages saying "expected =" or invalid character

Comment: When you say `A2` could be anything, what dictates `A2` changing? You could always assign the value to a variable and use that variable as a constant in your formula

Comment: @Zac would that just be as easy as Dim cell as Range, and using cell in place of "A2" in the formula?

Comment: Yes. But I would suggest not to use excel reserved words as that can confuse the issue. I tend to put an **"o"** or **"r"** infornt of my variables (i.e. `Dim rCell as Range`). However that doesn't resolve the issue in your formula. To do that, please tell us how `A2` changes?

Comment: @Zac the cell reference will just change depending on when I'm using the formula. There may be more or less columns of data, the formula will be run all the way down a column etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this to create a function:

```
Public Function Middlename(A As Range)

Middlename = Left(A.Value2, 6)

End Function
```

I guess for most of your function, you don't need `Application.Worksheetfunction`

`Left` and `Trim` works without
`Find` doesn't

So you need to use `Find` like this

```
Public Function Middlename(A As Range)

Middlename = Application.WorksheetFunction.Find("t", A.Value2, 1)

End Function
```

Comment: ++ I had to discard my answer :D

Comment: @pierre44 that's on the right track, but it's still not working. I'm going to add a mock up version so you can see the formula in it's entirety. I'm not asking you to write the whole thing, but if you spot anything in the formula that might be screwing with the function, that'd probably help lol

Comment: couldn't figure out how to add files so had to settle for an image

Comment: @C.Fsh You have to change all of your 'F2' by 'A', and then when you enter your formula in excel, you write middlename(F2)

Comment: @Pierre44 took me a while to get it perfect (there was some small issue with app.wsf.Substitute as well, but that's it working absolutely perfect